# Signature Capture on SO Invoice

Tags: acumatica

We currently have a requirement where an end user can perform a signature capture inside the SO Invoice screen.

End user would click a button or execute an action from the Actions Menu.  A touch screen graphical editor would come up allowing the user to use their finger or any hardware supported to create a signature image.  Upon clicking Accept, the image would be stored against the document Files attachment.

We are looking for something possibly already developed, or if necessary, a control we might be able to spawn that could then write the image attachment back.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since RuslanDev noted the mobile application for this, I'll share the MSDL code from the new T400 class on Customization of the Mobile Application.  I don't think this is what you were asking, but I'm adding as an answer to preserve formatting for those that may be looking for how to do this in Mobile.

To add to the mobile application on 2018 R2, use the new Mobile Applications section of the Customization Project.  Simply add the - add recordAction "SignReport" - section as shown below.

```
update screen SO301000 {
  update container "OrderSummary" {
        add recordAction "SignReport" {
          behavior = SignReport
          displayName = "Sign"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, at this point the functionality to create user signatures and attach the signature image file to an Acumatica ERP form that supports file attachments is exclusively available only in Acumatica mobile applications. I wish there were an Aspx control inside the framework, which could be used as is for that purpose, but unfortunately, there is not any to my knowledge.

An alternative approach is to create a custom **PXSmartPanel** embedding a custom HTML webpage (via the ***InnerPageUrl*** property). The custom HTML page can be used only to capture the signature and attach it to the current record inside Acumatica.